# Upload image and store to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

I'm getting back into programming once again and I'm currently stuck as I'm unable to upload an image to my database. 
  I  was reading some codes and answers last night and I'm still stuck here..It returns "New record created successfully" but nothing is being stored on my database. Hoping someone will help me to make a workaround on this one :) Thanks!

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Upload File:
    <input type="file" name="upload" /><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $servername ="localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "produ_db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  ){


$filename = $conn->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filedata= $conn->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));


if ($_FILES['upload']['name'] == 0 ){

echo "<br><br> New record created successfully";

}

else {
    /*where acc_cap is the image caption && acc_img is a blob type to store images*/
    $query = "INSERT INTO accessories(`acc_cap`,`acc_img`) VALUES ('$filename','$filedata')" ;
    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br><br> New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error:<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}
$conn->close(); 
}   

?>
```

Comment: It's more common to store files in the file system. For files larger than 100k, it really makes no sense to do otherwise.

Comment: Hi, just did and and made it to work, see my comment on manassehkatz :) Thanks for the information though :) Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You have:

```
echo "<br><br> New record created successfully";
```

twice - both in success (after INSERT) and failure (`$_FILES['upload']['name'] == 0`). Change the failure message so you can tell what is happening.

2 - Move:

```
$filename = $conn->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filedata= $conn->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
```

to following the test for `$_FILES['upload']['name']` as the file_get_contents function will fail if there is no file name.

3 - Checking my own code, it looks like I normally use `$_FILES['upload']['name'] == ''` rather than `== 0`. PHP often treats 0 and the empty string similarly but in this case I believe the empty string is the correct comparison as this is a string field when it has an actual filename.

4 - Generally considered bad form to store full image (or other) files inside the database - better to store in the file system (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php ) with just the filename in the database. That being said, sometimes it makes sense and I have stored full files in databases at times.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I'm currently checking this now :)

Comment: Okay, I'll review the #3 you mentioned afterwards I successfully upload the file. So I edited my code and added "error" as you've mentioned, thanks for noticing it: https://pastebin.com/FEBFshB3
I'm now getting "Error: unable to store Image"

Comment: Hi, I saw your edited post now :) I removed 0 and added '' as per your advise and i thank you for that :)
I'm now getting undefined variable on line 33: 
 $query = "INSERT INTO accessories(`acc_cap`,`acc_img`) VALUES ('$filename','$filedata')" ;
undefined variable filedata,filename..but the thing is, it printed new record created successfully and on my database, the blob file has 0kb and the acc_cap has blank data

Comment: @JimSteven - Check your assignment of filedata and filename - maybe echo them before running the INSERT query. If they are not assigned then PHP may put empty strings into $query which will be wrong (and generate the undefined variable error, depending on your PHP configuration) but still be a valid INSERT statement and therefore insert a blank record.

Comment: unsure why but I'm still unable to get it to work, the blob file was still 0 bytes but was successfully uploaded even though it has an error" undefined variable $filedata

Comment: @JimSteven - If you are still getting undefined $filedata then the assignment `$filedata = $conn->real_escape_string()` isn't working. Try breaking that assignment into a couple of pieces so you can check the result of of file_get_contents - i.e., see if there is an error and if there is no error then see how many bytes are read.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something here. base64_encode to make sure that the image (represented by blob file on sql) will be converted properly, currently doing it right now. Sorry for the late revert as well :)

Comment: Okay, I tried to var_dump($filedata) after the $query(after database insert) and it printed NULL, nothing is being stored.

Comment: Hi! I managed to fixed it using a different set of code and it is now uploading properly on database and printing images properly as well. Found a youtube tutorial and tweaked it a little.. https://pastebin.com/JCV8e8kN
Just want to know if you will consider this somehow safe? where should I put basenode64 to encrypt image name and mysql real escape string?
Thank you so much for your time to look into my issue :) Appreciate it a lot

Comment: @JimSteven - That looks much better. You are now storing the filename in the database instead of the file. The only thing - which you can check easily enough - is whether the filename stored in the database has the temporary directory (in which case you should change it to the target directory) or no directory (which would be fine).

Comment: Thanks so much..We'll have it checked as well :)